# How to use PushViewController on UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have an UIViewController in that I have a navigation bar and a table, now I want to navigate from this view to another view on selection of the table row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all add the new UIViewController to your application by right clicking in files and groups section and Clicking "**New File**" option and name it **SecondViewController**.

Make sure you add an XIB by selecting "**With XIB for user interface**" option while creating the SecondViewController

Suppose you want to push the new view on button click then add a button to you FirstViewController and add the following code on its button's **TouchUpInside** event:

```
 SecondViewController *secondView=[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
 [secondView release];
```

if you are using ARC then remove `[secondView release];`.

Let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
 FileName *file=[[FileName alloc] initWithNibName:@"FileName.xib" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:file animated:YES];
 [file release];
```